# How can I have the Instant Run button in IntelliJ like in Android Studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea

In Android Studio, the Instant Run button is right next to the Run button, however, in IntelliJ, that button is nowhere to be found, even though I have Instant Run enabled. Is the Instant Run button only available in Android Studio or is there another option that needs to be enabled in IntelliJ to make that button show up? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Instant Run button is only available in the Android Studio fork of the IntelliJ editor. If you want that functionality, you'll have to use Android Studio.

Comment: this comment is false.
I had this button in IntelliJ 2018. But now can not find it in 2019.